# Ionic HTTP request POST (works on postman) not working but GET works

Tags: laravel, typescript, http, ionic-framework, request

I was working with localhost and my IONIC app is almost done until I decided to host it on 000webhost. I uploaded my Laravel API which is very basic (I used CORS middleware) then when I tested the app, the GET request works but POST and PUT doesn't.

Notes:

- The URL is 100% correct because I'm using it on GET method
- Data 100% compatible because I test it on Postman and it works

This.http is the http service:

```
this.http.getData().subscribe(s => {
    console.log('Get Works');
    this.data = s[0];
    this.http.postData(this.data).subscribe(inf => {
      console.log('Post works');
    }, err => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log('Post dont work');
    })
  })
```

**the http service**

```
postData(data: any) {
  let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
  headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", '*');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json,text/plain');
  let requestOptions = { headers: headers }
  return this.http.post(url, data)}



 getData() {
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", '*');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json,text/plain');
let requestOptions = { headers: headers }
return this.http.get(url, requestOptions)}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYevg.jpg)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYevg.jpg)

solution :
for some reason it works on localhost but not in 000webhost ...
it doesn't accept body/row request maybe changing the 'content-type' will make it work thought
however my solution is using **HttpParams** from angular  :

```
postData(data: any) {
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", '*');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json,text/plain');
const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('type', data.type)
  .set('email', data.email)
  .set('uid', data.uid)
  .set('lat', data.lat)
  .set('lng', data.lng)
  .set('city', data.city)
  .set('municipality', data.municipality)
  .set('subject', data.subject)
  .set('description', data.description)
  .set('image', data.image)
  .set('upvote', data.upvote)
let requestOptions = { headers: headers, params: params }
return this.http.post(url, null, requestOptions)
```

}

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.http
      .post(url, data, { headers })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.